# Splitting payments to multiple merchants

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, braintree

Which is currently the best payment gateway and/or the best approach, when payments must be split to multiple destinations, for example the following case: 
I provide a platform for many merchants. Each time a merchant makes a sale, the end-user makes a payment, which must be split between the platform owner(me) and the specific merchant. Is there any payment processing gateway which provides such functionality globally(not in just one or a few countries).

And what if the payments are in range of 3-10$?

Also Would You prefer a more "static" approach - all payments going directly to the platform and any merchants has own money account, which can be pulled at some balance minimum (e.g. 20$)?

It seems that Stripe API has such functionality but the region, where the merchants could reside is limited to the USA only. The same seems to be valid for Braintree also.

Comment: Stripe connect! https://stripe.com/docs/connect I don't think it's US only. 2nd option is to do weekly `self-billing invoices`.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you believe the merchants would need to reside entirely in the USA?  Stripe supports a number of countries-- https://stripe.com/global

- Australia
- Austria
- Belgium
- Canada
- Denmark
- Finland
- France
- Germany
- Hong Kong
- Ireland
- Italy
- Japan
- Luxembourg
- Netherlands
- New Zealand
- Norway
- Portugal
- Singapore
- Spain
- Sweden
- Switzerland
- United Kingdom
- United States
- Brazil (BETA)
- Mexico (BETA)
- India (BETA)